# WCF Service hosted in a WinForm is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, .net-3.5

I want to create a very simple WebService (WCF) inside a Winforms application. To test this I created a WCF Service called Calculator inside my Winforms application. On the other side I created a simple Winforms application with a button to retrieve the Results of the service.

I  have added the Webservice as a reference to the testproject. It recognizes the two implemented methods and everything just fine. The problem is that I get no response from the webservice (freezing my testapplication). I have most likely forgot something on the Webservice application. What could it be?

Here's the webservice:

> ```
> [ServiceContract] 
> public interface ICalculator 
> {
>
> [OperationContract]
> double AddNumbers(double number1, double number2);
>
> [OperationContract]
> string TestMethod();
> ```
>
> }

```
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    #region ICalculator Member

    public double AddNumbers(double number1, double number2)
    {
        return number1 + number2;
    }

    public string TestMethod()
    {
        return "HELLO WORLD!";
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This is how I open the Webservice.

```
this.m_WebService = new ServiceHost(typeof(Calculator));
this.m_WebService.Open();
```

Here is the App.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Solution.Server.CalculatorBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Solution.Server.CalculatorBehavior"
        name="Solution.Server.Calculator">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Solution.Server.ICalculator">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Solution/Calculator/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

If I enter the URL (`http://localhost:8731/Solution/Calculator/`) in the Webbrowser I get this screen:

[image: Image of the Website]

Comment: Are you trying to host it all together? ... If so, there's 2 things. 1) Is there any code to start the service instance with `ServiceHost`? 2) There is no client configuration section in here either.

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot about the ServiceHost. Well looks like my Webservice is online and I can connect to it. But I can not use any methods, or I don't get the result from them.

Comment: Can you browse to it at `http://localhost:8731/Solution/Calculator/` ?

Comment: Added some information missing.

Comment: Is it possible something is wrong with my app.config?

Comment: There isn't a `client` section it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

With self hosting WCF services, the main Things to check are:

- Are you running in a Security context that allows you to start a httplistener?
- Are the ports that you are using blocked
- Configuration problem

Try testing With the WCF Test Client. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)